# How to configure titan to make it restore more quickly when resion server is down?

Tags: titan

I running titian in hbase 1.0.0-cdh5.4.0, Once a hbase region server down, my titan count not read/write hbase for nearly 5min. throgh my hbase table switch to new region server beyond 1 min. I don't know how to configure titan to let it not try to connect old region server for the last 4min. Can any one help me? Thank you!